# How to fix filter Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My filter should  return items in object when elements of object exists in array:

```
$scope.isCategory = function() {
    return function(item) {
        if($scope.filterObj.categories.length > 0) {
            return angular.forEach( $scope.filterObj.categories, function(value, key) {
                return (item.categories.indexOf(value) == -1);
            });
        }
        return item;
    }
};
```

Where `$scope.filterObj` is ["a", "b"] and `item.categories` is ["a"].

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.isCategory = function() {
    return function(item) {
        if($scope.filterObj.categories.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.filterObj.categories, function(value, key) {
                if (!found && item.categories.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            });

            return found ? item : null;
        }
        return item;
    }
};
```